# Modify the content of a file using Java

Tags: java, file-io, io, filereader, filewriter

I want to delete some  content of file using java program as below. Is this the write method to replace in the same file or it should be copied to the another file.

But its deleting the all content of the file.

```
class FileReplace
{
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;
    public void  doIt()
    {
        try
        {
            File f1 = new File("d:/new folder/t1.htm");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            while (line = br.readLine() != null)
            {
                if (line.contains("java"))
                    line = line.replace("java", " ");
                lines.add(line);
            }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f1);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            out.write(lines.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public statc void main(String args[])
    {
        FileReplace fr = new FileReplace();
        fr.doIt();
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you should use the name br only once ;)

Comment: 1) close the the reader after use: `br.close()`; 2) what is `out` in your code? 3) what is the result, what did you expect?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would start with closing reader, and flushing writer:

```
public class FileReplace {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;

    public void  doIt() {
        try {
            File f1 = new File("d:/new folder/t1.htm");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.contains("java"))
                    line = line.replace("java", " ");
                lines.add(line);
            }
            fr.close();
            br.close();

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f1);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            for(String s : lines)
                 out.write(s);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        FileReplace fr = new FileReplace();
        fr.doIt();
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 I can't find any `writeline` in `BufferWriter` also `Close` should lower case.

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer is great. However, there is an easier way to replace content in a file using Apache's `commons-io` library (`commons-io-2.4.jar` - you can use any latest versions)

```
private void update() throws IOException{
        File file = new File("myPath/myFile.txt");
        String fileContext = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
        fileContext = fileContext.replaceAll("_PLACEHOLDER_", "VALUE-TO-BE-REPLACED");
        FileUtils.write(file, fileContext);
 }
```

**Note:** Thrown `IOException` needs to be caught and handled by the application accordingly.

Comment: Why is this better? It seems like it is doing the same thing... or at the very least just copying the file to a string and rewriting the file? Why do you need Apache for this?

Answer (score 3):

Read + write to the same file simulatenously is not ok.

EDIT: to rephrase and be more correct and specific - reading and writing to the same file, in the same thread, without properly closing the reader (and flusing the writer) is not ok.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why ?

Comment: Yes, generally speaking, a reason would be because the offsets within the file will shift everytime you make a write and the read cursor will not keep track of that (see the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251058/java-read-and-write-a-file-together). Still, after rereading this question, the problem here was not that (i answered too fast), but a mattering of not closing and flusing.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to:

- `close` any stream when you no longer need them
- In particular *before* reopening it for writing.
- `truncate` the file, to make sure it shrinks if you write less than it had.
- then write the output
- write individual lines, don't rely on `toString`.
- `flush` and `close` when you are finished writing!

If you use *buffered* IO, you always have to ensure that the buffer is flushed at the end, or you might lose data!

Comment: I'm not sure he is reading/writing at the same time. He reads the lines into a list, then writes the list to file, or at least is attempting to.

Answer (score 0):

I can see three problems.

First you are writing to `out` which I assume is System.out, not an output stream to the file.

Second, if you do write to an output stream to the file, you need to close it.

Third, the `toString()` method on an `ArrayList` isn't going to write the file like you are expecting. Loop over the list and write each `String` one at a time. Ask yourself whether you need to write newline characters as well.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is slightly wrong. Here's the correct code.

```
    public class FileReplace {
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
String line = null;

public void  doIt() {
    try {
        File f1 = new File("d:/new folder/t1.htm");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("java"))
                line = line.replace("java", " ");
            lines.add(line);
        }
        fr.close();
        br.close();

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f1);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        for(String s : lines)
             out.write(s);
        out.flush();
                } 
        out.close();
   catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. "out.close()" should be out of "for" loop.

Comment: It is outside of the for loop. The `for` loop is only the next line, as the braces have been emitted.  You have put it outside of the `try` block. A better solution would have been to put the readers inside `using{...}` blocks