# How to write in a text file in java without deleting the content of the file before

Tags: java, file, text, filewriter, printwriter

This is code that deletes the content of the file then writes on it
I want to write in the file without deleting the content and write on the last line

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SetValues {

    public void setNumberPhone(String numberPhone) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter pr = null;

        try {
            input = new Scanner("C:/Users/Abdalrahman/Desktop/PhoneNumber.txt");
            pr = new PrintWriter("C:/Users/Abdalrahman/Desktop/PhoneNumber.txt", "UTF-8");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Not Open" + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }

        if (input.hasNext()) {
            pr.println(numberPhone);
        }
        pr.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: how about using file output stream ?

Comment: Read this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741751/modify-the-content-of-a-file-using-java

Comment: If you are using Java 7 or later, you can use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-. The option to append being `StandardOption.APPEND`

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.*;

OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("C:/Users/Abdalrahman/Desktop/PhoneNumber.txt"), APPEND);
PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(os);

pr.println("TEXT");
```

This will create an output stream wherein any output text will be appended to the current contents of the file. You can use the OutputStream to create a PrintWriter. More information can be found [at the Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newOutputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-)