# java: read and write on a file at the same time ,concurrency on file

Tags: java, file, nio, java-io

I want to write in a **text file** and read from that **at the same time**.
I want to use a text file as my database in a site and client 
can request to save sth on it.how can I save to, and read from a file
at the same time. I am **beginner** in java and I had an interview yesterday
and they ask me to do sth like that.

Thank you so much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206472/what-is-the-best-way-to-write-to-a-file-in-a-parallel-thread-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4251058/1952879

Comment: I strongly recommend you don't do this. I suggest you use a database as a database,